# Terminal Doesn't Say Whether Vagrant Box Installed Successfully or Not

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, laravel-5.5

I'm having some issues installing Laravel/Homestead. When I ran the `$ vagrant box add laravel/homestead`command everything went fine but I didn't see this line, `==> box: successfully added box 'laravel/homestead' (v0.4.2) for 'virtualbox'`!" However, when I run the `$ vagrant box add laravel/homestead`command again it shows the following below, which means that Laravel/Homestead was successfully installed, right? Or no? If not how would I delete all the vagrant files that I installed? Would I per the usual, go to the control panel and select uninstall program, or would that not be enough? Thanks for you help!

```
==> box: Loading metadata for box 'laravel/homestead'
    box: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/homestead
This box can work with multiple providers! The providers that it
can work with are listed below. Please review the list and choose
the provider you will be working with.

1) parallels
2) virtualbox
3) vmware_desktop

Enter your choice: 2
==> box: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v4.0.0) for provider: virtualbox
The box you're attempting to add already exists. Remove it before
adding it again or add it with the `--force` flag.

Name: laravel/homestead
Provider: virtualbox
Version: 4.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt did work, as the Vagrant is telling you that instance already exists... Use GitBash (assuming you are on windows) and once in terminal mode

```
cd ~/Homestead (or try cd ~/.Homestead)
vagrant up
```

If its all working - you will see the messages OK and if not, you'll get an error

Then you just go into your code folder where your projects will be created

```
cd ~/Code (code being the folder I want to create my Laravel projetcs)
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel nameofproject
```

Not sure if above helps. in my example, the homestead files are in the /users/myuser/Homestead folder - but best of luck

Comment: thankyou! I will try this out and get back with you. Laravel/Homestead seems to be an excruciatingly hard thing to install!

Comment: Its quite easy :) - just install Oracle VM with defaults and then Homestead - 10 mins and your done... If you get stuck, I'll dig up a link to a good tutorial for you...